# get original from a folder which is alias and symbolic link to another folder

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, directory

How to get original from a folder which is alias and symbolic link to another folder?
I have a directory structure. There is this folder A and B. Folder B is a link to folder B. When I get info of folder A, I see that it's kind is Alias. Size is just 12 bytes and it has a field named "original" which points to folder B.

I want to get path of this Original for folder A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `readlink` on the symbolic link to get its canonical path. See for e.g:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/test

$ ls -l 
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 zzuser  wheel  17 Nov  7 18:28 NewFolderB -> /tmp/test/folderb
drwxr-xr-x  2 zzuser  wheel  68 Nov  7 18:19 foldera
drwxr-xr-x  2 zzuser  wheel  68 Nov  7 18:28 folderb



$ readlink -n NewFolderB
/tmp/test/folderb
```

`readlink` also supports a few other options that might be of use to you. Look up the man page for more details.

Comment: Beautiful-iMac:~ agauravdeep$ readlink -f             /Volumes/iOSRestoreImages/SinkHole/CurrentSinkHole/            
readlink: illegal option -- f             
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]             
Beautiful-iMac:~ agauravdeep$ readlink --help            
readlink: illegal option -- -          
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]

Comment: `readlink` is effectively an version of `stat` and ONLY displays the target of symlinks. It will NOT show the target of an `OS X` Alias. `OS X` Finder calls symlinks and Alias the same thing, but they are quite different. The Unix layer of `OS X` has NO knowledge of `OS X` Alias.